# Zsh: complete the files in current directory no matter what command is

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh, macos

For example, when I just want to make cfiles without makefile:

```
$ make a<tab>
a1.c  a2.c  a3.c  ...
```

but seems that zsh would detect the command then completes nothing when I hit tab.

It works fine on bash that just lists everything.

Is there the ways like bash do?

My OS is macOS mojave with zsh 5.7.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `zsh` [FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq04.html):

Add this line to your `.zshrc`

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _ignored _files
```

This will perform standard bash file completion if `zsh` completion fails. You may also need to add

```bsh
autoload -U compinit && compinit
```

to you `.zshrc` file after setting the completer configuration.